# People logged into random users accounts using PHP sessions

Tags: php, session

I keep having complaints that users are logged in as each other. They can even edit their profiles and post as them...this is obviously a huge issue. People who arent even registered are visiting the site and seeing they are logged in as other people.

This happens in Safari and Firefox

My sessions are set when people log in using the `$_SESSION['variable'] = name;` system, so pretty standard. The sessions are cross subdomain using:

```
ob_start();
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.subverb.net');
session_start();
```

in the header of all my pages.

I have an `iframe` that holds the chat portion of the site which also contains the same header

I don't know what other info I can give, so please ask. I really need this to get sorted but not sure what the problem is!

Thanks

---

In response to below:

The standard login script is lifted straight from a Larry Ullman textbook:

```
if ($un && $p) { // If everything's OK.

    // Query the database.
    $query = "SELECT member_id, member_firstname, member_type, username FROM member WHERE (username='$un' AND password=SHA('$p')) AND active IS NULL";  

    $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) or trigger_error ("query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($query));

    if (@mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) { // A match was made.

        // Register the values & redirect.
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        $_SESSION['member_id'] = $row['member_id'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['member_firstname'];
        $_SESSION['member_type'] = $row['member_type'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
```

The facebook login script does the following:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE oauth_prov = 1 AND fb_userid = ".$user['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query ($dbc, $query) or trigger_error ("query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 ) {



    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {;


    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $row['member_firstname'];
    $_SESSION['member_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_uid'] = $row['fb_userid'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
```

All of the inputs are sanitized and there are not other ways for the user to add the details. Username and password added as normal, facebook id got from Facebook by clicking a link that executes the script.

These errors are happening well past login tho, or when login hasnt even happened. There is no other place where session values are set on the site.

Comment: Is the session id appended to the url ? This could cause session overtakes.

Comment: No. You mean when they log in or anywhere else? Nothing is appended to the URL when they log in (or anywhere else) as far as I'm aware. Just user_id and username are added to $_SESSION at login

Comment: Do you use any sort of caching? If a page gets cached when a user is logged in, that might cause an issue like this.

Comment: are the people getting the problem, logging in on the same physical computers?

Comment: There is on the blog pages (there is a blogging network on the site) but this occurred just now without them having visited the site ever before and on the home page which has no cacheing at all.

Comment: No, different users on different computers. Not happening often enough for them to find any pattern or obvious cause - and I cant ask them to do that anyway it would be far too time consuming for them

Comment: @Michael Mallett: Please show us you active [session configuration (`session.*` options)](http://php.net/session.configuration).

Comment: Is the "compromised account" always the same one? I.e., when they log in as someone else, is it always the same someone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check the database routine that logs the users in for holes. Are you certain that it's selecting the appropriate user and only the appropriate user? Have you tested whether your select statement is immune to different user input scenarios? Given that it persists across pageloads, it's almost certainly a `$_SESSION` problem. Assuming you load info about the user at login, it follows that the problem comes with the initial population of the `$_SESSION` variable during login. As such, you should definitely check the login script to make sure it's solid.

You may want to post other parts of your login script, so we can check it out for holes/problems.

Comment: It wont let me answer my own question for another 8 hours. But my script takes a username and password and checks the database returning: member type, member id and username and adding them to session variables. The facebook one checks the database for the facebook id that is given by the facebook login, returning the same into the sessions. All inputs are sanitized (the normal login is lifted from a fairly popular and long running textbook, so im confident it is appropriate)

Comment: I don't know how this can be the login script tho as this is happening well past logging and even when users haven't ever visited the login page

Comment: You don't have to include it as an answer, can just edit your original post. Regarding the second one, I clarified my answer to explain better, but does it occur for people who have never logged in before (i.e., have never had cookies set on their computer)?

Comment: Ok, ive just realised that in my facebook script it is assigning $row['user_id'] which should be member_id. I cant see how this would be causing the problem tho as this would just be adding nothing to the $_SESSION.

Comment: @michael - Glad I could help :) If the answer has been helpful, upvote!

Comment: Would this be the problem then do you think? Surely this would just add nothing to the session variable? I dont know how that would then make all the necessary sesion variables be set for another user, enough to even edit someones profile, which checks for user_id and username in the session?

Comment: @michael - I'm not sure what you mean. You have `$_SESSION['member_id'] = $row['user_id'];`. If the `$_SESSION['member_id']` is used elsewhere to determine who the user is, then of course that could be a problem; you're giving them the wrong ID. You'll have to test out different scenarios and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe There is a collision in thesession id? That.would explain the random part. To protect against this using a quick hack, store the IP in the session and throw a 'Sorry' page if IP changes. Do you have many visitors?

Comment: At the moment not many no, only just launched. Would it ake any difference to store the sessions in a database instead?

Comment: Then a collision should not be the cause : (  Storing the Data in a database will probably not fix this, as it seems to be a problem with your Session id or session setup.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever come to a solid conclusion on this?

It sounds like the login script whilst faulty was unlikely because of the random nature of it?